# wxwidget wxStaticText border

Tags: wxwidgets

i using wxWidget with Code:Blocks IDE and wxSmith GUI Builder. I want to create wxStaticText with line around wxStaticText (like border=1 in HTML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wxStaticText`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxstatictext.html) doesn't seem to support that style. Perhaps you could wrap it inside another control (say, a `wxPanel` ?). Not the cleanest solution, to be sure, but should work.